# How to put previous stacked bar visible over last stacked bar on Stacked Bar Chart?

Tags: css, bar-chart, javafx-8

When i create Stacked Bar Chart, i can intersect two stacked bar by changing initial scale-y property of one of them (Scrolling up or down). But the problem is, in the intersection area only last added bar is visible (last one is over previous bar). I think this is about the adding queue.Is it possible to reverse it?

I've tried some blendMode properties with css but i couldn't success it (For example, applying BlendMode.exclusion makes bar all transparent not just intersection area).

Here is my scale property css:

```
for (XYChart.Data data : datas) {
                data.getNode().setStyle("-fx-scale-y: 1.1;"}
```

How can i make visible the previous one instead of last one in the intersection area?

Comment: You should clarify the question.  A stacked bar chart already 'stacks' the bars on top of each other.  You can also use a normal bar chart where the series are side by side.  Maybe you're thinking of a 3D chart where the series are behind each other and viewed on some angle.  That, you can't do (yet).

Comment: @brian Please pay attention the "intersection" world. I've already know that that bars are on top of each other. But when you change the scale-y property of last added bar and scroll it down, you make two bars intersect. In this intersection area the visible bar is last added bar not the bottom sided bar. I mean the last added one is in front of previous one. Thank you for your interest.